# Get the date with 0 as time

Tags: sql

I'm using the following query to get the maximum days in a month as a datetime.

```
Select DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,'2014-01-01')+1,0))
```

The query result is: 2014-01-31 23:59:59.000

How can I get the following result : 2014-01-31 00:00:00.000

Thanks,

Comment: select DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)

Comment: syntax looks like sql server to me, hence the possible duplicate.